# Inflating the boundaries created with convex hull

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, convex-hull

I have a set of lan and lat points and have plotterd a convex hull for them using QGIS. A polygon is created along the set of points and plotting them on the MAP.

Now I am trying to inflate the size of this polygon (creating a new boundary around the previous convex hull) just to occupy more area on the MAP than before. Is there a trick which can be used in QGIS.

like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons).

Comment: could you tell why buffer won't do the job ?  TOOLS -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Buffer(s)

Comment: yes. that worked perfectly fine....